# Stop loop when getting a specific text response from server

Tags: node.js

I'm working with some API server that communicates by XML.

I need to send, let's say: 20 identical POST requests.

I'm writing this in Node JS.

Easy.

BUT - since I'm going to multiply the process, and I want to avoid flooding the server (and getting kicked), I need to break the sending loop IF the (XML) response contains a specific text (a success signal): `<code>555</code>`, or actually just '555' (the text is wrapped with other XML phrases).

I tried to break the loop based on the success signal AND also tried "exporting" it outside the loop (Thinking it could be nice to address it in the loop's condition).

Guess it's easy but being a newbie, I had to call for some help :)
Attaching the relevant code (simplified).

Many thanks !

```js
  const fetch = require("node-fetch");

  const url = "https://www.apitest12345.com/API/";
  const headers = {
    "LOGIN": "abcd",
    "PASSWD": "12345"
  }
  const data = '<xml></xml>'


  let i = 0;
  
  do {  // the loop
    fetch(url, { method: 'POST', headers: headers, body: data})
    .then((res) => {
       return res.text()
  })
  .then((text) => {
    console.log(text);

  if(text.indexOf('555') > 0) {  // if the response includes '555' it means SUCCESS, and we can stop the loop
    ~STOP!~ //help me stop the loop :)
  }
    
  });

  i += 1;

} while (i < 20);
```

Comment: You lost me in xml... we are in 2020...

Comment: Yes this API is from 2015 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simple for loop with async await.

```js
  const fetch = require("node-fetch");

  const url = "https://www.apitest12345.com/API/";
  const headers = {
    "LOGIN": "abcd",
    "PASSWD": "12345"
  }
  const data = '<xml></xml>'


  for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    const res = await fetch(url, { method: 'POST', headers: headers, body: data});
    if (res.text().indexOf('555') !== -1)
      break;
  }
```

Comment: YES, this was 99% of the solution, thanks.

I ended up with this:


  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(Date.now());
    const res = await fetch(url, { method: 'POST', headers: headers, body: data});
    
    const text = await res.text();
    

    if (text.indexOf('555') !== -1)
      break;
  }